# Keys should have a rotation policy ensuring that their rotation is scheduled within the specified number of days after creation not working

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have got the policy item called **Keys should have a rotation policy ensuring that their rotation is scheduled within the specified number of days after creation**. which keeps coming back as unresolved.

The key in question has the rotation policy defined below.
[image]

If I leverage the rotate now functionality, it doesn't resolve the policy item. Not sure what else needs to be done to resolve this.

Comment: Make sure you have the **"Key Vault Crypto Officer"** role permissions to manage key rotation policies. If you don't, assign the role, enable Managed Identity in the policy, and then grant the same role to Managed Identity.